# How to find income data by census tract or block?

Tags: data, united-states, census

I am trying to find a file with income data for every census tract.

On the American FactFinder/Census websites, I can find data for each individual state or county but I want **all** census tracts in all 50 states.

Does this mean I have to download all 50 files and combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [National Historical Geographic Information System](https://www.nhgis.org/).
I can't guarantee it will have what you are looking for, but it is certainly easier to use than American Fact Finder.

Comment: Looks like Census doesn't have it in this format.

Comment: Agree with @auto. I couldn't find income by census tract. I found it by larger geographies, but not by census tract.

Answer (score 1):

I found a full national dataset for blocks here:
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html

Comment: I am talking about demographic data that I can place onto this map data. Was I downvoted for this?

"These files do not include demographic data, but they contain geographic entity codes that can be linked to the Census Bureau’s demographic data, available on American FactFinder."

Comment: as far as i know there are no datasets that contain national data that are prebuilt, you can get state data by googling tiger line shapefiles.  this pdf (http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/education/tiger/Downloading_TIGERLine_Shp.pdf) shows what administrative areas are available, and national is not one

Comment: Yes, that's how the census data works. Look for Tiger files on the census. They're shapefiles of, for your purpose, census tracts and blocks. These have fields based on FIPS codes that you use to join to the FIPS codes in the tabular data. Just how it works. I think the census does put out some limited spatial data with demographics, but not entirely positive, or if it would have what you want. All 50 states will be <em>a lot<\em> of data.

Answer (score 1):

If you work for an organization that pays for access to Social Explorer, that tends to be easier to pull from than FactFinder.

Otherwise, in FactFinder, you have to add all tracts in each state one by one, but it should let you add all of them before downloading, keeping it all in one file.

I tested it and it let me add at least 3 states.